# I'm getting undefined error on a session variable i set even if i added session_start()

Tags: php, session

I'm login into this system though admin panel and then loading font end page which has session_start() at the top of the page and trying to echo session variables i set when admin login happens. but it gives me undefined index errors on session variables. But these are printing find in admin area. I have no idea why this is happening.

in front end

```
 session_start();
 echo("username = ".$_SESSION['username']."<br />");
```

p.s : important - it worked before. this is a system i have installed in many servers and i never encounter this error before. And even on this server it worked few days ago. Maybe customer changed something? a server configuration value? i have no idea. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($_SESSION)` after `session_start()` and paste the output here. We can then determine if the session variables exist or not. :)

Comment: thanks for your reply output of `var_dump($_SESSION)` is `array(0) { }`

Comment: Then nothing was saved to your session. Can you post the code where the session variable was written?

Comment: `if ($this->Users_obj[$user]->userName == $user && $this->Users_obj[$user]->passWord == $pass) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['log'] = true;}`

this is how it looks. But this is so weird since above code is in another page admin section of this system. i logged in though that admin section. Then in the index page of that admin i printed session variables and printing fine . but then i refresh front end and print the same session variables it gives these errors.

Comment: Are the admin section and front ends on different domains or subdomains? Check that the same cookie is sent for both requests in firebug. In the "net" tab look at the request and look for `PHPSESSID=fdkg0234o0lfsdgo43dfdf` or something similiar, make sure this value is used for requests when you hit the front end of the site.

Comment: oh.. its different id's . front end is `/` and admin section is in sub-folder `/admin`

Comment: I don't think that should matter though unless those 2 folders are under different virtual hosts. have you checked the cookie ids?

Comment: Try setting your session cookie to your domain `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' ); //Note the dot infront of the domain`.

Comment: where do i have to put that code in..?

Comment: In all your scripts before everything else. You could however, as a test just put it at the beginning of the script that sets the sessions vars and the beginning of the script that reads the vars, just to see if it works first.

Comment: well i did... in admin everything is included to index.php. so on top of it i put that and on front end as well. but i still get this error :(

Comment: set the session.cookie_path to "/" using ini_set, and place it in a file that is included in every script (probably the config/application file); that ensures that the session cookie uses the root folder, and every file in every folder can make use of it

Comment: oh, finally figured it out . it was my browser , i cleared cookies and it worked. sorry for giving u such a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any white space in the file before session_start();? This is the most common cause of session issues... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just doing `session_start();` do this `if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();`